# C++ class for disjoint-set/union-find on integers

Tags: c++, algorithm, union-find

I have implemented the [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). The purpose is to group integers together. For example, if I want to find out the groups of integers where each adjacent neighbors are same:

```
vector<vector<int>> test = {
{1,0,0,1},
{0,0,0,1},
{0,3,3,1}};
```

There are 4 groups of integers, namely:

- Group 1: 1 at (0,0)
- Group 2: 0's at (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0)
- Group 3: 1's at (0,3), (1,3), (2,3)
- Group 4: 3's at (2,1), (2,3)

Here is the code in C++:

```
//This union-find class implements two optimization ideas:
//1)path compression
//2)union by rank


class DisjointSet {
    public:
    DisjointSet(int num_nodes);
    int find(int element);
    void do_union(int elment_a, int element_b);
    void dup(vector<int> &v);
    private:
    vector<int> parent_, rank_;
};

DisjointSet::DisjointSet(int num_nodes):
    parent_(num_nodes),rank_(num_nodes, 0)
{
    for(int i=0; i<num_nodes; ++i) parent_[i] = i;
}

int DisjointSet::find(int element)
{
    if(parent_[element] == element) return element;
    //1)path compression
    return parent_[element] = find(parent_[element]);
}

void DisjointSet::do_union(int a, int b)
{
    if(parent_[a] == parent_[b]) return;
    int fa = find(a), fb = find(b);
    //2)union by rank
    if(rank_[fa] < rank_[fb]) {
    parent_[fa] = fb;
    } else {
    parent_[fb] = fa;
    if(rank_[fa] == rank_[fb]) rank_[fa]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain how you get from a `vector<vector<double>>` to "four groups of integers"? How do we interpret `test`?

Comment: @200_success I've changed it to vector<vector<int>>
basically two integers can be grouped together if the have same value and are adjacent.(but not diagonally)

Answer (score 5):

Seems pretty straightforward. By the way, "disjoint-set" is a less common name for this data structure than "union-find", at least in my experience.

You have several typos in your code; you should always fix those. Sure, the computer doesn't care, but we don't write C++ code for the computer; we write it for the human reader. `elment_a` should be `element_a`; you should either implement `dup` or remove its declaration; and you should use proper indentation.

```
class DisjointSet {
public:
    DisjointSet(int num_nodes);
    int find(int element);
    void do_union(int element_a, int element_b);
private:
    std::vector<int> parent_;
    std::vector<int> rank_;
};
```

Notice also that I added the missing `std::`s to your `vector`s (and by the way you should `#include <vector>`), and split each member variable declaration onto its own line so that the struct layout is easier to see at a glance.

---

Who says using `rank_` is an optimization? It feels to me like a pessimization, because you're trading O(N) extra space (and more convoluted code) for something like O(lg N) faster lookups. I do see that e.g. [Boost.DisjointSet](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/disjoint_sets/disjoint_sets.html) implements "union by rank" as well, but I'd be interested in seeing some benchmark numbers on your particular use-case.

---

```
return parent_[element] = find(parent_[element]);
```

Modern C++ (like modern any-other-language) strongly prefers *not* to mix side effects into the middle of expressions, except in idiomatic cases such as `*p++ = ...`. Prefer to put the assignment in its own statement.

```
parent_[element] = find(parent_[element]);
return parent_[element];
```

---

```
int fa = find(a), fb = find(b);
```

Same deal as above: prefer to put each variable declaration on its own line for readability.

```
int fa = find(a);
int fb = find(b);
```

And then use proper indentation in what follows:

```
if (rank_[fa] < rank_[fb]) {
    parent_[fa] = fb;
} else {
    parent_[fb] = fa;
    if (rank_[fa] == rank_[fb]) rank_[fa]++;
}
```

Basically, though, looks good. Looks like you picked the right level of abstraction for this particular problem: not too scattered (keeping related things in a nice neat class), but not too libraryish (you hard-code `int`, for example, instead of going all in with templates).

Comment: >> Who says using rank_ is an optimization? 
See "Introduction to Algorithms, Second Edition" by Thomas H. Cormen. Chapter 21.3 Disjoint-set forests. There is proof, that using those two heruistics in conjuction makes the running time linear.